# Jasmine Karma not working Angular 16 upgrade

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, angular16

I have upgraded **angular from 15 to 16** but when I run ng test, it is not including any component.spec.ts files and it fails all the test cases:

**package.json:**

```
    "karma": "6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.4.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-auto-spies": "^8.0.1",6
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "target": "es2021",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "facebook-js-sdk"],
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "app/shared/components/*",
        "app/core/components/*",
        "app/route-controller/pages/virtual-visits/components/*",
        "app/route-controller/pages/virtual-visits/components/schedules-visits/components/*"
      ],
      "@pipes/*": ["app/shared/pipes/*"],
      "@services/*": ["app/core/services/*"],
      "@directives/*": ["app/shared/directives/*"],
      "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
      "@builders/*": ["app/domain/builder/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["app/domain/entities/*"],
      "@enums/*": ["app/domain/enums/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["app/domain/interfaces/*"],
      "@domain/*": ["app/domain/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["app/pages/*", "app/route-controller/pages/*"],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["src/app/route-controller/pages/**/mocks/*.json"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-typescript'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,
      suppressErrorSummary: false,
      suppressFailed: false,
      suppressPassed: false,
      suppressSkipped: false,
      showSpecTiming: false,
      failFast: false,
    },
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'lcovonly' },
      ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 50,
          branches: 15,
          functions: 45,
          lines: 50,
        },
      },
    },
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    reporters: ['spec', 'progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '../../../../test-reports/angular/', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null, // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.ERROR,
    browsers: ['CustomChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      CustomChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
  });
};
```

I am not sure what am I missing here. I am getting below error when do `ng test`:

[image: ng test result]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have `describe` blocks with no `it` tests.

Something like this:

```
describe('abc', () => {
  // empty here, no it('...
});
```

It seems like it does not like this.

If you don't have the above, what I would do is I would generate a blank Angular 16 project and compare the `angular.json`, `karma.conf.js`, `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `karma.conf.js` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files to hopefully see what could be causing the issue.